# Conditional validation of subclass

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have ASP.NET MVC 3 application with the following class:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }

  // [Optional("MailingAddrressSameAsHome")] - some custom attribute
  public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }

  public bool MailingAddrressSameAsHome { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
  [Required]
  public string Street { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

And now I would like to validate, mailing address only when MailingAddressSameAsHome is false. Unfortunatelly I don't known how to stop validating properties in Address class.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider only setting MailingAddress when needed, thus letting the property MailingAddrressSameAsHome be read-only:

```
    public bool MailingAddrressSameAsHome 
    {
      //Null means no MailingAddress, which means: use HomeAddress
      get { return MailingAddress == null ; } 
    }
```

If so, you can validate MailingAddress whenever present.

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: No because ASP.NET MVC doesn't support this

Answer (score -2):

You could write this with a custom attribute

Comment: It's always a good idea to show how you would achieve that instead saying it. The community of SO is big and nobody has the same knowledge or level. ;)